# I have a 8000/5000 watt generator with 20 amp/240 4 prong . Can I upgrade it to a 30amp/240?

Tags: generator

I have a 8000/5000 watt generator with 20 amp/240 4 prong . Can I upgrade it to a 30amp/240 ?

Comment: A 5000 watt(8000 just for short start ups) is a tiny bit over what a 20 amp(4800w) will give.  A 30 amp plug will not give any more juice.  If you need it to plug something in, that does not need more than 20 amps, then you can.

Comment: Are those numbers peak-8000  and continuous run-5000?

Comment: What size breaker is on the generator, and what is the power requirement of the device you wish to plug in?   Probably better initially to focus on whether the generator and your needs are compatible, and if not why not, than to focus on the plug/socket interface because you can splice anything to anything, and that's probably not what you want to know.

Answer (score 4):

If you talking about upgrading the generator so you can get 30 Amps instead of 20 Amps, like tapping into the 8000 peak for more than a few seconds, no you can't. You'd have to replace the generator.  If you're just talking about replacing the outlet to accommidate a few cords you have around, then that you can do but you'll still only get 20 Amps out of it. The outlet is not the limiting factor.

Answer (score 3):

Can/should you hack the generator to have a different socket?  No, that'll void the warranty, risk damage, violate Code (NEC 110.3), and affect insurance if there's a loss.

Can you use an adapter cable? Absolutely.

Can you make an adapter cable?  Sure. You just need some 10/4 **cordage** (not to be confused with 10/3 Romex, don't use that) and the appropriate plug and socket. If hardware store doesn't have them, an electrical supply house will.